# Episode file not being generated

Tags: jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am building a project using the maven-jaxb2-plugin

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
```

I set the episode parameter

```
<episode>true</episode>
```

However I see that no .episode file is being generated. I need this file so that this project can be used as an episode in another dependent project.

In the maven build logs I do see these logs which indicate that the episode & episodeFile parameter supported by xjc are not supported by the plugin:

```
[WARNING] Unknown plugin option: -episode
[WARNING] Unknown plugin option: C:\projecdir\src\main\generated-sources\META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode
```

Is this a bug in the plugin? Also is there any known workaround for this.

**Update**: Something strange happens when `useDependenciesAsEpisodes` is not false

**useDependenciesAsEpisodes = true**

When this was true it shows the warning above. This build works but no episode file is generated.

**useDependenciesAsEpisodes = false**

When I set this to false the episode file is generated.

However I had some additional arguments passed for a plugin which break the build.

```
<args>
    <arg>-typeId=7000</arg>
    ...
</args>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException: unrecognized parameter -typeId=7000
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArguments(Options.java:817)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2.OptionsFactory.createOptions(OptionsFactory.java:91)
    ... 24 more
```

I have to remove the additional args for this to work. However I need those arguments for some jaxb plugins (like shown [here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide)) used along with maven-jaxb2-plugin

```
<configuration>
    <extension>true</extension>
    <args>
        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
        <arg>-Xequals</arg>
        <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
        <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
    </args>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version><!-- version --></version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</configuration>
```

Comment: plugin version? I'm currently using version 0.12.1 and everything works fine. As alternative look for `<args />`

Comment: version 0.8.3. I will try upgrading. I did try the args, but that did not work

Comment: single `<arg>` must have `-` in front like `<arg>-episode</arg>` and `<arg>-episodefile target.episode</arg>`

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci added some more explanation for the issue I am seeing

Comment: is plugin responsible for `typeId` arg parsing included in `<plugins>`? usually this is the cause

Comment: Yup typeid is for plugin

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and [jaxb2-basics](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-basics) here.

Episode generation is [tested quite thoroughly](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests/episodes) on each release, so I'm pretty sure it works.

`useDependenciesAsEpisodes` just adds all your dependency JARs as "episode" JARs, this should not influence episode generation.

`-typeId=7000` is a bit suspicious, which XJC plugin processes this command? If none, this may potentially interfere with `-episode`, so this is where I'd look first.

What really helps is to see the `mvn clean install -e -X` log. It should lok the arguments finally passed to XJC, so there you could spot irregularities.

If nothing helps, put a minimal reproducing test project together and commint/send me a PR for this project in https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-support ex. under `e/episode-file-not-being-generated`.

Comment: Thanks @lexicore. typeId is a parameter needed for a custom plugin (I didnt build it, but have to use it to customize the model generation). I do not know how the <args> section works, but seems like the plugin is supposed to consume the args (which the custom plugin is not doing, maybe?) since <arg>-XtoString</arg> works with jaxb2-basic, but when I add typeId it breaks. However useDependenciesAsEpisodes somehow changes this behavior and the arg -typeId works. I am trying to reproduce this issue using 1 of the samples and will post a PR if valid.